# Has anyone heard about newfolder virus?

Tags: virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Recently I am experiencing a new kind of virus. Its newfolder.exe virus. My antivirus is AVG and it cannot remove this virus. It is blocking the empty space of my hard disk. Any suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: Must have had caps lock on by mistake. Thanks @ChrisF

Answer (score 1):

you need to find this file and delete it.

svichossst.exe

I have not tried this and it is just what I have herd through the google vine.

Although this is not a programming question the thought of a herd of wild folders scares me.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this helpful. It describes how to remove the virus. http://www.usbvirus.com/new-folder-virus/remove-new-folder-exe-virus.html

I have not tried this as I have never had this virus. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at some of the Bootable stand alone Virus scanners. I use Kapersky and BitDefenders versions.

There's a good review [Here](http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/) that contains links to download the various Programs.